# Adjust Javascript Code to Control Scrolling of Body

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays

I have created a modal wherein it has functionality to open and close multiple modal windows one by one

**When even one modal window is opened** , i want the body to stop Scrolling and Scroll again only **when all modal windows are closed**

To fix this i added below lines to the JavaScript section which deals with opening and closing of modal windows

```
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
```

And

```
document.body.style.overflow = "scroll";
```

While this works well but just partially , there's one issue yet to be fixed ,
if i have multiple modal windows opened and i proceed the close the second one , the body scroll gets activted even while the first window is still open ( this happens probably because the JavaScript code logic thinks a window is closed so it triggers the body scroll back again )

But i have multiple windows , please someone edit the JavaScript code below so that the body scrollabilitiy gets activted only after **all** the open windows are closed and not just **one** of them

( I am attaching the Javascript code in snippet for reference )

Javascript

```js
let open_modals = [];

$(function() {

  // Get the button that opens the modal
  // read all the control of any type which has class as modal-button
  var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-button");

  // All page modals
  var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

  // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
  for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
      modal.style.display = "block";
      open_modals.push(modal.id);
      document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    }
  }
  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].onclick = function() {
      for (var index in modals) {
        if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined' && modals[index].id == open_modals[open_modals.length - 1]) {
          modals[index].classList.add("modal-content-active");
          var item = modals[index];
          document.body.style.overflow = "scroll";

          setTimeout(function() {
            item.classList.remove("modal-content-active");
            item.style.display = "none";
            open_modals.pop();

          }, 400);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //   When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
      for (var index in modals) {
        if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined' && modals[index].id == open_modals[open_modals.length - 1]) {
          modals[index].classList.add("modal-content-active");
          var item = modals[index];
          document.body.style.overflow = "scroll";

          setTimeout(function() {
            item.classList.remove("modal-content-active");
            item.style.display = "none";
            open_modals.pop();

          }, 400);
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Update - Even tho changes are needed in JavaScript only , some people recommend to include to whole codes as few things are interlinked

**Whole codes + Output here -** https://jsbin.com/gizivacosi/edit?output

Comment: It would help here if we could see an example of the html for at least two modals in the context of your other HTML. Reason being this line seems backwards from the comment: `if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {`

Comment: Sure.  Here is the whole code along with output - https://jsbin.com/gizivacosi/edit?output

Comment: I also updated it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that will check if any modal is open renable scroll:

```
function checkRenableScroll () {
    if (!open_modals.length) {
      document.body.style.overflow = "scroll";
    }  
}
```

Then, remove both `document.body.style.overflow = "scroll";` from your closing functions, and call `checkRenableScroll()` inside the setTimeout.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    item.classList.remove("modal-content-active");
    item.style.display = "none";
    open_modals.pop();
    checkRenableScroll(); // call the function
}, 400);
```

Answer (score 1):

Break this up, remove duplicated code, remove global variable, watch out for those events, sniff out the modals.

```js
function setScroll() {
  let activeModals = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content-active");
  document.body.style.overflow = !!activeModals.length ? "hidden" : "scroll";
}

function modelOpen(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  let modal = document.querySelector(event.target.getAttribute("href"));
  modal.classList.add("modal-content-active");
  setScroll();
}

function modalClose(event) {
  let modal = event.target.closest('.modal')
  setTimeout(function() {
    modal.classList.remove("modal-content-active");
    setScroll();
  }, 400);
}

function modelCloseAll(modals) {
  for (let m = 0; m < modals.length; m++) {
    modals[m].querySelector(".close").click();
  }
}
$(function() {
  var openBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-button");
  var modals = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');
  var closeSpans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
  for (let i = 0; i < openBtns.length; i++) {
    openBtns[i].addEventListener('click', modelOpen, false);
  }
  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  for (let i = 0; i < closeSpans.length; i++) {
    closeSpans[i].addEventListener('click', modalClose, false);
  }
  // Listen for click events outside all modals
  document.body.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    let inModal = event.target.closest('.modal');
    if (inModal == null) {//clicked outside all modals
      modelCloseAll(modals);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  border: 1px green inset;
  background-color: #FFEEFF;
  padding: 1em;
}

.modal-content-active {
  display: block;
}

.modal .close {
  border: solid #aaaaaa 1px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #EEFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="myContainer">
  <div class="modal" id="one">
    <span class="close">X</span> I am modal 1 so what
    <button type='button'>Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal" id="two">
    <span class="close">X</span> I am modal 2 so what
    <button type='button'>Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cheese">
    <span class="spanner">X</span> I am NOT a modal so what
    <a href='#one' class="modal-button">Button 1</a>
    <a href='#two' class="modal-button">Button 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```